# Using Eclipse, how to delete a file which has been in GitHub but should been in .gitignore file?

Tags: git, eclipse, egit

If a file "a.txt" has been committed and pushed to a GitHub repo but I want to ignore it now.

Using git bash, I could use `git rm --cached a.txt` and a new line "a.txt" in `.gitignore` to delete this file in the GitHub repo.

But what should I do if I use Eclipse ?

Comment: Do you want to delete the file "from git" _without_ deleting it on your local system?

Comment: Yes, I don't want to delete it physically, just ignore it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Eclipse allows you to mark files as `Untracked` by right-clicking on the file and selecting `Team`>`Advanced`>`Untrack` even if that file is present in the `.gitignore`.:

[image]
(I removed some unnecessary parts of the context menu)

This will essentially do the same as `git rm --cached`.

Then, the file will be marked as deleted in the `Staged Changes` part of the `Git Staging` menu:

[image]

After doing that, just commit and push the (staged) changes.

Of course, nothing stops you from using the command-line. Even if you use Eclipse, you can still enter some commands via the command-line and do some other stuff with Eclipse/EGit.